# ajax sometimes running sometimes not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

i have a problem regarding my ajax, i am adding a data from my database, and i am trying to refresh my div. Sometimes it work's great but sometimes it isn't. Why is it?.

Here is my code, where i have a function addtoqueue and inside of its success, i have put a div refresher so that after adding in my database, i will refresh my div. Sometimes it works well but sometimes it's not, i tried it in many many times and it has always failure. Why?

```
function addtoqueue(patient_id) {
  if(getClinicID != undefined ) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to add this in queue?")) {
      $.ajax({
          url: siteurl+"myclinic/patientaddqueue",
          type: "POST",
          data: {patient_id:patient_id,clinic_id:getClinicID},
          dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
              refresh_afterdel(getClinicID);
              alert("Patient Successfully Added");
            }
      });
    }
  }
  else{
    alert("There is no clinic selected");
  }
}
```

Here is my refresh_afterdel function with full code:

```
function refresh_afterdel(getClinicID) {
$("#queue").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_patients_refresh/"+getClinicID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.length>0) {
              $("#queue").empty();
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              $('#queue').append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+
                                  '<div class="panel-heading">'+'<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'">'+data[i]['order_num']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'<div id="patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+'<div class="panel-body">'+'<div class="row">'+
                                  '<div class="col-sm-5">'+'<small>Patient ID: <label id="patientID">'+data[i]['patient_id']+'</label></small>'+''+'<button onclick="checkstatus('+data[i]['patient_id']+','+data[i]['queue_id']+');this.disabled=true;" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Check me up</button>'+'<button onclick="checkstatus1('+data[i]['patient_id']+');" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs ">View History</button>'+
                                  '<button onclick="removequeuedoc('+data[i]['queue_id']+');" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnmarg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Remove &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>'+'</div><!-- col-sm-4 -->'+'<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                                  '<div class="img-patient">'+'<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url('+data[i]['patient_photo']+')"></div>'+'</div><!-- img-patient -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->'+'</div><!-- row -->'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-body -->'+'</div><!-- panel-collapse -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
            };            
          }
        }
  });  
}
```

Now here is the screenshot of my console which shows that , after i clicked the button addtoqueue the refresh_afterdel doesn't run. The red label in my screenshot must be followed by get_patients_refresh as it is the ajax of the refresh_afterdel function, take a look in the label blue, it shows the correct running of my function.
[image]

Comment: Isn't this just asynchronous operations taking an indeterminate amount of time?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for your reply, Sir i have an asynchronous function in other function which in screenshot the checkingUpdates, but is it affecting the process? . it's not part of my addtoqueue code?

Comment: ln 2: getClinicID can either have a value or be null, it can not ever be equal to undefined. You're looking for `typeof getClinicID != 'undefined'` to see if the variable has been initialized or not.

Comment: @Chase getClinicID can be null sir, because it is a selectbox.

Comment: any answers sir?

Answer (score 0):

To help find the problem, I recommend that in addition to "success", you add handlers for other events too (for example "error"). Then you can see if your query fails for some identifiable reason.

Also if you are only observing the code execution by checking whether the subsequent "refresh_afterdel" function launches new ajax request, you may consider adding console log entries (or alerts if you must) in earlier parts of execution, to see where it fails.

Comment: i already added alert, the alert also doesn't execute but when i check the query , it is fine, the data was added